Lookup using accumulator in xslt3.0 not returning values
I have below aggregated input in xml from two different sources and I have created the xslt with three accumulators to help me with the lookup. I am not sure what I am missing or need to fix in order to return the value after looking up. Its returning a blank currently.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<aggregate-data>
<weci:Workers_Effective_Stack xmlns:weci="urn:com.workday/weci">
    <weci:Worker>
        <weci:Worker_Summary>
            <weci:Employee_ID>11829</weci:Employee_ID>
        </weci:Worker_Summary>
        <weci:Effective_Change weci:Sequence="0">
            <weci:Derived_Event_Code>TER</weci:Derived_Event_Code>
            
        </weci:Effective_Change>
    </weci:Worker>
</weci:Workers_Effective_Stack>
<persons xmlns:ext="urn:calabriopersons">
    <person>
        <personid>00404e33-0c24-4846-b7db-b074006f4f25</personid>
        <wiserid>11829</wiserid>
    </person>
    <person>
        <personid>0043eeb1-1456-4ddf-b97c-b100009a79e9</personid>
        <wiserid>14119</wiserid>
    </person>

</persons>
</aggregate-data>

My xslt code with the 3 accumulators and the lookup is as below.
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wtdf="urn:com.workday/weci/tdf"
    xmlns:weci="urn:com.workday/weci"
    xmlns:ext="urn:calabriopersons"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="WorkerIDLookup CurrentLookupvalue"/>
    
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:accumulator name="CurrentLookupvalue" as="xs:string" initial-value="''" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="ext:personid/text()" select="."/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    
    <xsl:accumulator name="WorkerIDLookup" as="map(xs:string,xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="ext:wiserid/text()" select="map:put($value, string(.), accumulator-before('CurrentLookupvalue'))"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    <xsl:accumulator name="weciWorker" as="xs:string" initial-value="''" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="weci:Workers_Effective_Stack/weci:Worker/weci:Worker_Summary/weci:Employee_ID/text()" select="."/> 
    </xsl:accumulator>
    <xsl:template match="weci:Workers_Effective_Stack">
        
        <xsl:apply-templates
            select="copy-of(weci:Worker)[weci:Effective_Change/weci:Derived_Event_Code = 'HIR' or weci:Effective_Change/weci:Derived_Event_Code = 'TER']"
            mode="some-non-streamable-mode"/>
    </xsl:template> 
    
    <xsl:template match="weci:Worker"
        mode="some-non-streamable-mode">
        
        <xsl:for-each select="weci:Effective_Change[weci:Derived_Event_Code = 'TER']">
            
            <Set-Leaving-Date>
                
                {
                "PersonId": "<xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('WorkerIDLookup')( accumulator-before('weciWorker') )"/>"
                 "Date": "2024-06-27"
                }
            </Set-Leaving-Date>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Expected output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Set-Leaving-Date xmlns:ext="urn:calabriopersons"
              xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
              xmlns:weci="urn:com.workday/weci"
              xmlns:wtdf="urn:com.workday/weci/tdf">
            
            {
            "PersonId": "00404e33-0c24-4846-b7db-b074006f4f25"
             "Date": "2024-06-27"
            }
        </Set-Leaving-Date>

However it is returning a blank
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Set-Leaving-Date xmlns:ext="urn:calabriopersons"
              xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
              xmlns:weci="urn:com.workday/weci"
              xmlns:wtdf="urn:com.workday/weci/tdf">
            
            {
            "PersonId": ""
             "Date": "2024-06-27"
            }
        </Set-Leaving-Date>

Any advise please
Thanks
Arthi

The weci:Worker is placed in the XML input before the person elements, that way with streaming it is processed before all those person elements and their content that capture the values for CurrentLookupvalue and WorkerIDLookup. Therefore you use of accumulator-before('WorkerIDLookup')( accumulator-before('weciWorker') certainly can't find anything because the elements you want to process to accumulate data are not yet processed.
So you need to rethink your approach, as you say the input is aggregated from different sources maybe you can rearrange the order of aggregation.
It also appears the elements you have shown wear a namespace declaration but are itself in no namespace so the rules should be e.g.
<xsl:accumulator name="CurrentLookupvalue" as="xs:string" initial-value="''" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="personid/text()" select="."/>
</xsl:accumulator>

<xsl:accumulator name="WorkerIDLookup" as="map(xs:string,xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="wiserid/text()" select="map:put($value, string(.), accumulator-before('CurrentLookupvalue'))"/>
</xsl:accumulator>

When I change the input order, use all three accumulators explicitly and make the above change the field in the output is populated, at least with Saxon HE 12 not using streaming.
To work with streaming I think you need to rewrite two accumulators to store the string value of the text node and not the text node itself:
<xsl:accumulator name="CurrentLookupvalue" as="xs:string" initial-value="''" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="personid/text()" select="string()"/>
</xsl:accumulator>

<xsl:accumulator name="WorkerIDLookup" as="map(xs:string,xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="wiserid/text()" select="map:put($value, string(.), accumulator-before('CurrentLookupvalue'))"/>
</xsl:accumulator>

<xsl:accumulator name="weciWorker" as="xs:string" initial-value="''" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="weci:Workers_Effective_Stack/weci:Worker/weci:Worker_Summary/weci:Employee_ID/text()" select="string()"/> 
</xsl:accumulator>


It works if I keep and use the 3rd accumulator also. I just do not need to give the full xpath from the input for the employee id. It can simply be  <xsl:accumulator name="weciWorker" as="xs:string" initial-value="''" streamable="yes">
<xsl:accumulator-rule match="weci:Employee_ID/text()" select="string()"/>
</xsl:accumulator>

Thank you so much! It worked!

I reordered the input
Added name space to the elements in my input
Changed the accumulators to pull the string values
It still did not work so I did below also
Removed the 3rd accumulator and instead handled by passing the id(lookup key) directly into my query within the for-each.

My new xslt is as below
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wtdf="urn:com.workday/weci/tdf"
    xmlns:weci="urn:com.workday/weci"
    xmlns:ext="urn:calabriopersons"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="WorkerIDLookup CurrentLookupvalue"/>
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:accumulator name="CurrentLookupvalue" as="xs:string" initial-value="''" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="ext:personid/text()" select="string()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    
    <xsl:accumulator name="WorkerIDLookup" as="map(xs:string,xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="ext:wiserid/text()" select="map:put($value, string(.), accumulator-before('CurrentLookupvalue'))"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    
    
    
    <xsl:template match="weci:Workers_Effective_Stack">
        <xsl:apply-templates
            select="copy-of(weci:Worker)[weci:Effective_Change/weci:Derived_Event_Code = 'HIR' or weci:Effective_Change/weci:Derived_Event_Code = 'TER']"
            mode="some-non-streamable-mode"/>
    </xsl:template> 
    
    <xsl:template match="weci:Worker"
        mode="some-non-streamable-mode">
        
        <xsl:for-each select="weci:Effective_Change[weci:Derived_Event_Code = 'TER']">
            <xsl:message expand-text="yes">WorkerIDLookup {accumulator-before('WorkerIDLookup') => serialize(map { 'method' : 'json', 'indent' : true() })}</xsl:message>        
            <Set-Leaving-Date>
                {
                "PersonId": "<xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('WorkerIDLookup')(../weci:Worker_Summary/weci:Employee_ID)"/>"
                "Date": "2024-06-27"
                }
            </Set-Leaving-Date>
        </xsl:for-each>
        
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>

Really appreciate the quick response and the advise. Highly Grateful!
Arthi
